# How to get call stack of a handled exception using EurekaLog

Tags: delphi, eurekalog

I'm using Delphi 7 and EurekaLog 7 (in compatibility mode) and simply want to get call stack of a handled exception, like

```
procedure CrossThreadFunc;
begin
  try
    SomeCode;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Log(CallStackOf(E));
  end;
end;
```

It's a multi-threaded application so I'd like to see the call stack of the calling thread if possible. Also, since this is a handled exception, do I still need to use EurekaLog's `OnExceptionRaise` event? (which I don't want to).

Edit: CrossThreadFunc() is being called many times with some arguments and what I need to know is exactly where I called it that eventually caused SomeCode() to raise an exception.

Comment: It's not clear which call stack you are looking for. The worker thread, or the main thread. And if the latter, at what point in time?

Comment: David, I'm actually interested in seeing the calling thread's call stack because `SomeCode()` is causing an exception but I need to know where exactly I called `CrossThreadFunc()` that caused the exception.

Comment: This is probably the wrong way to debug your program. You'd need to suspend the main thread to get its call stack. No guarantee that it would be useful info because you'd have missed the instant that caused the original error.

Comment: Is using Eurekalog an absolute requirement? If you are by chance already using Jedi you could do that with Jedi's stack tracing utility.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, described in [EurekaLog's help](https://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/how_to_get_exception_call_stack.php):

**Option 1**

(Delphi 2009+ only)

Assuming you only need a textual representation:

```
except
  on E: Exception do
    Memo1.Lines.Text := E.StackTrace;
end;
```

**Option 2**

Assuming you have access to RTL's exception object:

```
uses
  EExceptionManager, // for ExceptionManager
  EException,        // for TEurekaExceptionInfo 
  ECallStack;        // for TEurekaBaseStackList 

var
  EI: TEurekaExceptionInfo;
  CallStack: TEurekaBaseStackList;
// ...
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      EI := ExceptionManager.Info(E);
      // EI would be nil, if EurekaLog is disabled
      // or event handlers instruct EurekaLog to skip this exception
      if Assigned(EI) then 
        CallStack := EI.CallStack;
    end;
  end;
```

Note: due to bugs in some older IDEs, you may need to write like this:

```
EI := ExceptionManager.Info(Pointer(E));
```

**Option 3**

Assuming you have access to EurekaLog's exception information object (such as argument in an event handler):

```
uses
  EException, // for TEurekaExceptionInfo 
  ECallStack; // for TEurekaBaseStackList

{ ... } AExceptionInfo: TEurekaExceptionInfo; { ... }
var
  CallStack: TEurekaBaseStackList;
begin
  CallStack := AExceptionInfo.CallStack;
end;
```

**Option 4**

Assuming you want call stack for last (e.g. most recent) exception in current thread:

```
uses
  EExceptionManager, // for ExceptionManager
  EException,        // for TEurekaExceptionInfo 
  ECallStack;        // for TEurekaBaseStackList 

var
  EI: TEurekaExceptionInfo;
  CallStack: TEurekaBaseStackList;
begin
  EI := ExceptionManager.LastThreadException;
  // EI would be nil, if EurekaLog is disabled
  // or event handlers instruct EurekaLog to skip this exception
  if Assigned(EI) then 
    CallStack := EI.CallStack;
end;
```

**Notes:**

- If you need current call stack - use `GetCurrentCallStack` function from `ECallStack` unit:

  uses
    ECallStack; // for TEurekaBaseStackList and GetCurrentCallStack

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    CallStack: TEurekaBaseStackList;
  begin
    CallStack := GetCurrentCallStack;
    // You can also use other functions from ECallStack unit
    try
      Memo1.Lines.Text := CallStack.ToString;
      // You can also use CallStackToString(s) routines to customize textual formatting
    finally
      FreeAndNil(CallStack);
    end;
  end;
- If you need call stacks from other threads - just set it up in options, call stacks for all enabled threads will be included in the same call stack object. You can distingush between threads by `ThreadID` property of call stack entry.
- If you need to convert retrieved call stack to text/string representation for logging purposes, see [this](https://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/how_to_convert_call_stack_to_text.php):

**Option 1**

Use `StackTrace` property of exception object (Delphi 2009+):

```
except
  on E: Exception do
    Memo1.Lines.Text := E.StackTrace;
end;
```

**Option 2**

Use `ToString` method to convert call stack to single string with default formatting:

```
var
  CallStack: TEurekaBaseStackList;
begin
  CallStack := { ... somehow retrieve call stack ... };
  Memo1.Lines.Text := CallStack.ToString;
end;
```

**Option 3**

Use `Assign` method to convert call stack to `TStrings` object with default formatting:

```
var
  CallStack: TEurekaBaseStackList;
begin
  CallStack := { ... somehow retrieve call stack ... };
  Memo1.Lines.Assign(CallStack);
end;
```

**Option 4**

Use `CallStackToString` function from `ECallStack` unit:

```
// (CallStackToString function allows you to override header and formatting)

var
  CallStack: TEurekaBaseStackList;
  Formatter: TCompactStackFormatter;
begin
  CallStack := { ... somehow retrieve call stack ... };

  // A): Default formatting and header:
  Memo1.Lines.Text := CallStackToString(CallStack);

  // B): With custom header:
  Memo1.Lines.Text := CallStackToString(CallStack, 'Error Details:');

  // C): Custom formatting:
  Formatter := TCompactStackFormatter.Create;
  try
    // <- here you can customize Formatter (for example: alter captions for columns, etc.)
    Memo1.Lines.Text := CallStackToString(CallStack, '', Formatter);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Formatter);
  end;
end;
```

**Option 5**

Use `CallStackToStrings` function from `ECallStack` unit:

```
// (CallStackToStrings function allows you to override header and formatting)

var
  CallStack: TEurekaBaseStackList;
  Formatter: TCompactStackFormatter;
begin
  CallStack := { ... somehow retrieve call stack ... };

  // A): Default formatting and header:
  CallStackToStrings(CallStack, Memo1.Lines);

  // B): With custom header:
  CallStackToStrings(CallStack, Memo1.Lines, 'Error Details:');

  // C): Custom formatting:
  Formatter := TCompactStackFormatter.Create;
  try
    // <- here you can customize Formatter (for example: alter captions for columns, etc.)
    CallStackToStrings(CallStack, Memo1.Lines, '', Formatter);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Formatter);
  end;
end;
```

Available formatters are:

- TEurekaStackFormatter - general formatter for EurekaLog-style call stack (i.e. fixed-width table with columns) - best to be used in text files
- TEurekaStackFormatterV6 - backward-compatibility formatter to produce call stack in EurekaLog V6 format (less columns)
- TSimpleStackFormatter - produces list-like view of call stack (no columns) suitable for variable-width fonts (best to be used in message boxes)
- TCompactStackFormatter - similar to TSimpleStackFormatter, but produces more compact output with less details (good for quick preview)

P.S. You may also want to consider [EurekaLog's logging procedures](https://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/logging.php).